# Error al insertar un nuevo registro en ASP.NET Core

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, postman

estoy insertando un nuevo registro en ASP.NET Core utilizando Linq , pero me da error estoy insertando el registro a una tabla que creé con una columna calculada que toma de referencia el primary key de esa tabla , al insertar un registro en el scrip de sql ingresa sin problemas , pero utilizando postman me da ese error ¿En que estoy fallando?

este es mi controlador

```
[HttpPost("crearEntrega")]
        public ActionResult crearEntrega([FromBody] Entrega en)
        {
            DateTime fechaCrear = DateTime.Now;
            Entrega entrega = new Entrega
            {
                ent_mat = en.ent_mat,
                ent_uni_med = en.ent_uni_med,
                ent_alm = en.ent_alm,
                ent_lot = en.ent_lot,
                ent_can = en.ent_can,
                ent_cho = en.ent_cho,
                ent_nom_cho = en.ent_nom_cho,
                ent_rut = en.ent_rut,
                ent_pla = en.ent_pla,
                ent_fec_cre = fechaCrear,
                ent_usu_cre_sap = en.ent_usu_cre_sap,
                ent_fec_mod = en.ent_fec_mod,
                ent_usu_mod_sap = en.ent_usu_mod_sap
            };
            _quimpacContext.Entrega.Add(entrega);
            _quimpacContext.SaveChanges();
            return Ok(entrega);
        }
```

este es mi tabla en sql server

```
create table entrega(
ent_cod_ent int primary key identity (1,1),
ent_mat varchar(100),
ent_uni_med varchar(50),
ent_alm int ,
ent_lot int,
ent_can int ,
ent_cho nvarchar (10),
ent_nom_cho varchar (100),
ent_rut int ,
ent_pla nvarchar (20),
ent_fec_cre datetime,
ent_usu_cre_sap nvarchar(10),
ent_fec_mod datetime,
ent_usu_mod_sap nvarchar(10)
);

alter table entrega 
add ent_cod_pro as Concat(Replicate('0', 5 -len(ent_cod_ent)),ent_cod_ent) Persisted
```

este es el json que envio en postman

```
{
        "ent_mat": "Material 12",
        "ent_uni_med": "Kg",
        "ent_alm": 14256,
        "ent_lot": 300,
        "ent_can": 75,
        "ent_cho": "1542-a",
        "ent_nom_cho": "aldair zavala",
        "ent_rut": 123,
        "ent_pla": "asdv12",
        "ent_fec_cre": "1900-01-01T00:00:00",
        "ent_usu_cre_sap": null,
        "ent_fec_mod": "1900-01-01T00:00:00",
        "ent_usu_mod_sap": null,
        "ent_cod_pro": "00001"
}
```

error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

lo podrías solucionar mediante un  `TRIGGER` una vez que el registro sea creado por lo tanto la llave primaria ya ha sido asignado y lista para utilizar.

Ejemplo:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Update_ent_cod_pro 
    ON entrega
    AFTER INSERT
    AS  
       DECLARE @ent_cod_ent int           
       SELECT @ent_cod_ent = ent_cod_ent FROM inserted  
      
       UPDATE entrega SET ent_cod_pro=Concat(Replicate('0', 5 -len(@ent_cod_ent)),@ent_cod_ent) WHERE ent_cod_ent=@ent_cod_ent
        
    GO
```

Answer (score 1):

La columna calculada no es algo que le envies al motor de la base de datos, es algo que se calcula en función de algo en el registro. En el caso, el valor de `ent_cod_pro` se calculará, en base al valor que disponga `ent_cod_ent`.

La sentencia no puede mencionar la columna `ent_cod_pro`, ya que de esa columna lo único que podemos hacer es obtener valores. De la misma manera que no la mencionas en tu controller.

El Json que envías debiera de ser:

```
{
        "ent_mat": "Material 12",
        "ent_uni_med": "Kg",
        "ent_alm": 14256,
        "ent_lot": 300,
        "ent_can": 75,
        "ent_cho": "1542-a",
        "ent_nom_cho": "aldair zavala",
        "ent_rut": 123,
        "ent_pla": "asdv12",
        "ent_fec_cre": "1900-01-01T00:00:00",
        "ent_usu_cre_sap": null,
        "ent_fec_mod": "1900-01-01T00:00:00",
        "ent_usu_mod_sap": null
}
```